# Software Development and product Version Numbers?

Tags: version

What determines what version number a program or release should be?

For an example: Version 2012.1.0.125
Or: 1.0.269
and so on.

What determines what the Version Number is?

Comment: It's not what, but who. Either it's the project manager, or it's the marketing department.

Comment: @JBNizet: And sometimes both, such as with Windows NT 5.1, more widely known by the marketing department's name, Windows XP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this varies from project to project. These are just my observations:

- Some projects use *dates*: e.g., 2011.11.12.1 for the first release on November 12th, 2011. Most projects will have *some* [boneheaded mistake](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/B/brown-paper-bag-bug.html) that necessitates a near-immediate re-release of a new, fixed version, so the `.1` at the end will eventually be called into being, if it wasn't there from the start.
- Some projects use major.minor.subminor version numbers; typically, the *subminor* number will incremented for bugfixes. When enough bugfixes have been collected, or a new feature that's really neat has been introduced, then the *minor* number is usually incremented. Bumping the *major* number is often reserved for releases that break [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/API) compatibility. (*Sometimes* releases that break [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) compatibility are done with minor version updates, but hopefully those are rare and not common.)
- Some projects use a CVS or SVN checkin identity, or some "build number" to represent builds, as part of the version numbers. These typically include larger numbers such as your `125` or `269`. These numbers are chosen because they are nicely [monotonic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic), but don't carry much meaning themselves.

Answer (score 2):

Typical industry *convention* is Major.Minor.Build with a transition from 0.x to 1.x indicating Beta to Production. Let me repeat, it's a *convention* and not a law of man or nature or a marketing department.